# Asterisk Originate a muted call

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

i have a script that start a call from some channels in my asterisk
this scripts runs the folowing commands:

```
channel originate SIP/11 extension 800@from-internal
channel originate SIP/12 extension 800@from-internal
channel originate SIP/13 extension 800@from-internal
channel originate SIP/14 extension 800@from-internal
```

after that i ned to mute each channel using python amy integration like it:

```
        action = SimpleAction(
            'MuteAudio',
            Channel='SIP/11-00001',
            Exten='11', 
            Direction='in',
            State='on'           
        )
```

but it gives me to mutch errors, if a channel dont start a call this command never runs.

id like to know if tehre is any commando that can originate a call muted. and after that i can choos what channel will be unmuted based on my system status.

Answer (score 0):

You can mute audio in from-internal context as first priority.

You can originate via Local/ channel to do any Dial command params or any apps before call.

Comment: do you have any example how to do it please?

Comment: There are plenty samples in offical docs, common. https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+Callfiles+and+Local+Channels